# Debug Project in PhpStorm

Tags: php, magento, debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I have been searching for a satisfactory answer on the net and StackOverflow without success. How should I debug Magento as a whole application — not a single file — using the [PhpStorm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)? You can do this in Visual Studio, Netbeans, and IntelliJ IDEA but I need to know how to debug an application, such as Magento, using PhpStorm.

When I try to run the debugger on a controller, such as `C:\xampp\htdocs\coinandbuillion\app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\CartController.php`, a bunch of errors get thrown because PhpStorm is trying to execute the file directly rather than working through the application dispatcher in `index.php`.

So does anyone know how to debug automatically from the initialization point of application till the end?

Here is snapshot what i got. I cant debug after that button click.

[image]

Comment: I know you can compile your PHP code with Facebook's HipHop, when used in debug mode you can debug your entire project.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to execute your controller file directly ... instead of doing actual app debugging. Have you seen these links yet? It has all info: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne , I tried App debugging too , but it starts and ends directly without debugging. Can any one explain me how do I debug app properly ?

Comment: Please show screenshots/screencast of such debug configuration -- maybe you are doing it wrongly.

Comment: @LazyOne , as per video I tried all . I used `listen to debug connection` etc. Now when I goto https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/ . I entered liscence no. and press Bookmark for start debug, but Nothing happens.

Comment: @LazyOne , I mean I am not able to use Debug now from chrome. Rather it debugs from Phpstorm code only on its own. I want to debug from browser, when i hit btn , it will debug in editor, now it doesnt.

Comment: What you have described as your solution is different to what you have asked originally (PHP's own server vs XAMPP environment) .. but it works for you (which is an important) so it's all good.

Comment: @LazyOne eventually debugging is important and my question title says the same , thats it. And I know there are 10000 people who are confused with Whole project debugging. Lets face it , it was difficult :) But did it! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I did it !!! :) Please refer steps I followed.

**Install** Jetbrain's **chrome extension** from **[Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji)**.

Now follow steps as below.

[image: chrome extension]

[image: Steps to activate phpstorm debugging for Whole Project automatically when you refresh page to trigger Phpstorm Debugger automatically !!!!]

In 3rd snapshot in image. your Built in server port(mine is 63342) may be different for you,I didnt change it , it was already there(default), I have just shown it. I changed other options only.

**That's it !!**

**Edit 1:**

IF you have problem writing all xdebug setting in php.ini from diagram 1, here it is text version: **Don't change paths exactly like i have** because you may have xampp/wamp installed on other drive, in different folder. So please add paths like zend_extension accordingly.

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
;xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C\xampp\tmp"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

**Ensure following :**

1. **Ensure you have Installed Chrome Extension from [Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji)**
2. Make sure xampp/wamp server is running.
3. Make sure Xdebug debugger is configured.

   **If not** , Goto File->Settings -> search PHP and follow diagram as follows

[image: xdebug]