# Debugging with PhpStorm locally

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

Kind of a noob question. I'm uploading to a remote server. I've been advised to debug locally (versus remotely).  How am I to pull up my files in a browser, then use the debugging tools in PhpStorm? As it stands, my remote host (in PhpStorm) is configured. I've done my own research but can't seem to find a clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm

Comment: refer this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124782/debugging-project-in-phpstorm . I answered.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "zero-configuration" debugging as described in [docs](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm). Also if in trouble try this xdebug settings:

```
; path to your php_xdebug extension file
; download from https://xdebug.org/wizard.php
zend_extension="c:\xampp-php7\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.4.0-7.0-vc14.dll"
; disables profiler globally 
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
; allows enabling it selectively with request parameter "XDEBUG_PROFILE"
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
; directory to output profiler files to
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\xampp-php7\tmp"
; profiler file name (with request uri and timestamp)
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "%R-%t.cgout"
; enables debugger
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
; selects the dbgp protocol
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
; host where debug client is running
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
; debugger port
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
; disables xdebug traces in error messages - use https://tracy.nette.org/ instead
xdebug.default_enable = "Off"
; makes sure that the process does not freeze when there is no debug client
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
```

I created a [gist for easier sharing](https://gist.github.com/tomasfejfar/4e8e27ece29b142a7ec7f54f4fa44872)